# How can I get user input in web form using Visual Basic

Tags: input, webforms, get

I am developing a web application and accessing data stored in SQL Server. I have a web form based on a Master Page, in which I present data to the user from an SQL Table, allowing the user to change the values and click a button to save the data back to the table. My problem is, when the user clicks the button, I can't get the values keyed by the user, instead, I get the original values from the SQL table.

I am using standard textboxes, for example:

```
< asp:TextBox ID="txtDesArt" runat="server" Width="489px"></asp:TextBox>
```

To fill the textboxes with initial values, I make a connection to SQL Server in the Page_Load, fill a DataTable in memory, and then fill the textbox, for example:

```
txtDesArt.Text = dtArticulos.Rows(0).Item("DesArt")
```

This is the code for the button:

```
< asp:Button ID="cmdGuardar" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="9pt" Text="Guardar" />
```

When I try to access the value of the field, it shows the original value, I've tried with:
txtDesArt.Text,
also with:

```
Request.Form.GetValues("txtDesArt")
```

Comment: Just for the record, I have another web form for adding data to SQL Server, I use the same objects and methodology, with the difference that I don't initialize the textboxes, and it works fine when I use txtDesArt.Text

Comment: Be sure to initialize the textboxes in `Page_Load` event only when `isPostBack` property is false, otherwise at each postback it will overwrite textboxes values with original values